# Splitting string with token

Tags: c, string, split

I am trying to delete .txt extension from filename that is written in string "mat":

```
sscanf(mat, "%s.txt", ime_datoteke);
```

If `mat="sm04567890.txt"` I want that `ime_datoteke="sm04567890"`.
As in example I tried using `sscanf`, but it doesnt work (it copies mat to ime_datoteke).

How can I do it in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify your `sscanf` approach slightly to read a string that does not include a `.`:

```
sscanf(mat, "%[^.].txt", ime_datoteke);
```

However, it would be best if you look for the `.` character from the end of the string, and then copy the substring determined by it.

```
char* dot = strrchr(mat, '.');
strncpy(ime_datoteke, mat, dot - mat);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [strrchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strrchr/):

```
char* pch = strrchr(str,'.');

if(pch)
   *pch = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

This example uses [`strrchr()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftw0heb9(v=vs.71).aspx) to locate the last period in the string, and then copies only the part of the string that preceeds that period.

If no period is found, the entire string is copied.

```
const char *fullstop;

if ((fullstop = strrchr(mat, '.')))
    strncpy(ime_datoteke, mat, fullstop - mat);
else
    strcpy(ime_datoteke, mat);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the Standard C function `strstr`:

```
char a[] ="sm04567890.txt";
char *b = strstr(a, ".txt");
*b = '\0';
printf("%s\n", a);
```

will print:

`sm04567890`